# Find and insert a string inside a text file inside a specfic block

Tags: bash, shell, insert

I have the following:

```
server {
            listen IP; 
            location /nginx-status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            allow $IP;
            deny all;
        }
```

My problem is, I need to insert this specifically inside the HTTP block in my nginx.conf file.

This is what a nginx config typically looks like:

http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample

I don't know if this is possible or not. I'm guessing it would be easier if I inserted right after the http block?

Ideally, I would like to do this in BASH but I am open to other options.

Answer (score 1):

One way using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim). Assume `nginx.conf` with the data you provided in the link and `infile` with the content that you want to add:

```
vim -u NONE -N -c '
    set backup | 
    bn | 
    execute "normal ggyG" | 
    bn | 
    execute "normal! gg/^\\vhttp\>\<CR>f{%P" | 
    xa
' nginx.conf infile
```

**How does it work?**

`set backup` creates a backup of `nginx.conf` appending a `~`. The original will be modified in-place.

`bn` changes between both files. The first `execute` command copies all content of `infile` and second `bn` returns to the `nginx` file.

The second `execute` command searches the line that begins with `http`, set cursor in the opening curly brace (`f{`) and use `%` to set cursor magically in the closing one. Then with `P` paste the content saved in the previous `execute` command.

And `xa` saves modified file and exits.